# Перенос данных в архивную таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возник вопрос, как сделать перенос данных из таблицы А в таблицу Б.
Таблица А содержит столбец дата и др.
Таблица Б имеет аналогичное строение.
Есть даты с 01.01.1990 по 31.12.2000
Из таблицы необходимо перенести только данные с 1990 по 1998 год включительно.
Так как записей много, нужно переносить по месяцу, как это сделать циклом?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Партицированием можно если нужен автомат

Comment: Настройте секционирование по месяцам и переключайте секции из текущей таблицы в архивную - это быстрая операция, потому-что она выполняется на уровне метаданных, а не строк. Но будьте готовы к деградации производительности, т.к. поиск по ключу будет выполняться для каждой секции. В общем учитывайте недостатки этого подхода.